# How to get first td tag innerText after specific class

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of Html and i want to get first `<td>` class, how can i do it?

```
<div class="className">My Class</div>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

First of all i get the class

```
var Myclass = document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0];
```

Bu then i cannot figure out how should i navigate to td value.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".className + table td")`?

Comment: This is a typo in your JS `wdocument` and you have two closing div tags. Please fix your example.

Comment: And class is a reserved keyword...

Comment: @Bergi thanks bu one problem i will need specify index of the class since on the page there is several classes with that name, how cna i do it with querySelector?

Comment: So the class is not important at all, you just want to get the next `<td>` after a specific element (that was before selected by index etc).

Comment: yes exactly i'm just moving forward from this class to get the td element by there is a lot of different tables without any class so i need to get the first td after this specific class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to pure vanilla js, the simplest answer would probably be:

`document.querySelector('.className td').innerHTML;`

This is assuming your HTML is structured like below. It's kinda unclear since you have two closing div tags:

```
<div class="className">My Class
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I need something like this `var c = window.document.querySelectorAll("className")[4].innerHTML;` but getting td as well

Comment: Why not `var td = window.document.querySelectorAll('td')[0].innerHTML`?

Comment: In that case you can chain your querySelectors: `window.document.querySelector(".className").querySelector("td").innerHTML`.

Comment: i need something like this: `var officers = window.document.querySelectorAll('.LeftHeaderRed')[4].querySelector("td").innerHTML;`  but this returns null when i use second querySelector

Comment: It could be an issue with the javascript, it could also be an issue with the html structure. I would recommend breaking it down piece by piece and seeing what's missing. Start with `var officers = window.document.querySelectorAll('.LeftHeaderRed')[4]`, and then add `querySelector("td")` and finally `innerHTML`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154472/discussion-between-andrew-and-joseph-cho).